# is it possible for exporting only functions in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible for exporting only the functions in MySQL workbench. 
Exporting is possible for stored procedure, but don't know how to export functions in MySQL workbench?

Answer (score 4):

You can export the create syntax function using the [SHOW CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-function.html):

```
SHOW CREATE FUNCTION [func_name]
```

Or using the Forward Engineer Wizard(Ctrl+G)

[image]

Then select the `MySQL Routine Objects` to export functions:

[image]

Finally:

[image]

Comment: this will show the function name. Need to get all the functions exported.

Comment: By doing like this ,got both the stored procedures and functions. I need only the function part.

Comment: Hmmm.. as you can see in the exported file/script, you can sort out there the sp's and function. I think there is no other way.

Comment: Or you can click "Show filters" and manually select the function alone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on Data export in the Management section on the left side.
2. Select the schema (Dont select any tables)
3. Check Dump Stored procedures and functions.
4. Click Start Export.

This will dump only the procedures and function and no data.

Comment: For me when I do this like you mention it export all tables

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem and I solved it by opening the *.sql file via notepad and deleted the drop and create table queries.